# AWS API Accesing from openvpn ip

Tags: aws-api-gateway, openvpn

Hi everyone I am restricting my API gateway to an OpenVPN IP using this article https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-resource-policy-access/
The problem is that when I reload multiple times sometimes it shows me data and sometimes it  shows me this {"Message":"User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on resource: arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-}
I want that it can't show other than the IP address i have given thanks in advance

Comment: What is the actual problem? *I want that it can't show other than the IP address i have given* is a bit unclear to me unfortunately. Are you sure that your IP isn't changing mid reload?

Comment: I mean by that is the IP address I am mentioning in API gateway resource policy it should be accessed with only them